Including Library in Office Addin for Production Build
I am writing an office addin for Excel. The code I have written has a dependency on the mathjs and accounting libraries. I am developing in Visual Studio Code.
To simplify I built the Excel addin with custom functions and a shared runtime in TypeScript. I edited the taskpane.ts file to include:
import { erf } from "mathjs";

at the beginning and modified the run function to call this.
export async function run() {
  try {
    await Excel.run(async (context) => {
      /**
       * Insert your Excel code here
       */
      const range = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();

      // Read the range address
      range.load("address");

      // Update the fill color
      range.format.fill.color = "yellow";
      range.values = [[erf(0.5)]];
      await context.sync();
      console.log(`The range address was ${range.address}.`);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

To get this code to work, I ran npm install mathjs in a terminal from Visual Studio Code. This works in development.
The problem I have is that "npm run build" fails with
> excel-custom-functions@0.0.1 build
> webpack --mode production

assets by status 263 KiB [cached] 14 assets
orphan modules 2.18 MiB [orphan] 1017 modules
runtime modules 2.59 KiB 10 modules
cacheable modules 2.12 MiB (javascript) 13.1 KiB (asset)
  modules by path ./node_modules/core-js/ 601 KiB 576 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/seedrandom/ 26.5 KiB
    modules by path ./node_modules/seedrandom/lib/*.js 16 KiB 6 modules
    modules by path ./node_modules/seedrandom/*.js 10.5 KiB 2 modules
  modules by path ./src/ 1.41 MiB (javascript) 1.48 KiB (asset)
    modules by path ./src/taskpane/ 1.41 MiB (javascript) 1.48 KiB (asset) 3 modules
    ./src/commands/commands.ts 876 bytes [built] [code generated]
    ./src/functions/functions.ts 1.57 KiB [built] [code generated]
  + 5 modules

ERROR in ./src/taskpane/taskpane.ts + 325 modules
Unexpected end of JSON input
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at ConcatenationScope.matchModuleReference (C:\Users\dabr4604\OfficeAddinApps\TestMultipleTSFiles\node_modules\webpack\lib\ConcatenationScope.js:132:13)
    at ConcatenatedModule.codeGeneration (C:\Users\dabr4604\OfficeAddinApps\TestMultipleTSFiles\node_modules\webpack\lib\optimize\ConcatenatedModule.js:1192:41)
    at C:\Users\dabr4604\OfficeAddinApps\TestMultipleTSFiles\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:3505:22
    at C:\Users\dabr4604\OfficeAddinApps\TestMultipleTSFiles\node_modules\webpack\lib\Cache.js:97:5
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\dabr4604\OfficeAddinApps\TestMultipleTSFiles\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at Cache.get (C:\Users\dabr4604\OfficeAddinApps\TestMultipleTSFiles\node_modules\webpack\lib\Cache.js:79:18)
    at ItemCacheFacade.get (C:\Users\dabr4604\OfficeAddinApps\TestMultipleTSFiles\node_modules\webpack\lib\CacheFacade.js:115:15)
    at Compilation._codeGenerationModule (C:\Users\dabr4604\OfficeAddinApps\TestMultipleTSFiles\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:3498:9)
    at C:\Users\dabr4604\OfficeAddinApps\TestMultipleTSFiles\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:3403:11
    at arrayIterator (C:\Users\dabr4604\OfficeAddinApps\TestMultipleTSFiles\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:3467:9)
    at done (C:\Users\dabr4604\OfficeAddinApps\TestMultipleTSFiles\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:3527:9)
    at C:\Users\dabr4604\OfficeAddinApps\TestMultipleTSFiles\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:3417:8
    at C:\Users\dabr4604\OfficeAddinApps\TestMultipleTSFiles\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:3531:6
    at C:\Users\dabr4604\OfficeAddinApps\TestMultipleTSFiles\node_modules\webpack\lib\HookWebpackError.js:67:2
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\dabr4604\OfficeAddinApps\TestMultipleTSFiles\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at Cache.store (C:\Users\dabr4604\OfficeAddinApps\TestMultipleTSFiles\node_modules\webpack\lib\Cache.js:111:20)
    at ItemCacheFacade.store (C:\Users\dabr4604\OfficeAddinApps\TestMultipleTSFiles\node_modules\webpack\lib\CacheFacade.js:141:15)
    at C:\Users\dabr4604\OfficeAddinApps\TestMultipleTSFiles\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:3530:11
    at C:\Users\dabr4604\OfficeAddinApps\TestMultipleTSFiles\node_modules\webpack\lib\Cache.js:97:5
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\dabr4604\OfficeAddinApps\TestMultipleTSFiles\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at Cache.get (C:\Users\dabr4604\OfficeAddinApps\TestMultipleTSFiles\node_modules\webpack\lib\Cache.js:79:18)
    at ItemCacheFacade.get (C:\Users\dabr4604\OfficeAddinApps\TestMultipleTSFiles\node_modules\webpack\lib\CacheFacade.js:115:15)
    at Compilation._codeGenerationModule (C:\Users\dabr4604\OfficeAddinApps\TestMultipleTSFiles\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:3498:9)
    at C:\Users\dabr4604\OfficeAddinApps\TestMultipleTSFiles\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:3403:11
    at arrayIterator (C:\Users\dabr4604\OfficeAddinApps\TestMultipleTSFiles\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:3467:9)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:85:11)

webpack 5.96.1 compiled with 1 error in 6122 ms

How to I properly include this library in the production build?
I checked that mathjs is included in the dependencies in the package.json.
I tried using externals in the webpack.config.js file. This allowed npm run build to work, but the addin no longer loaded in development.
I tested that npm run build:dev works
